# how to fix my connection class?

Tags: c#

Im newbie in C#

I put my database connection to a class:

```
public class Connection
{
    public string SetConnection()
    {
        string connectionstring = "server=SURI-PC;database=cms;Integrated Security=True";
        return connectionstring;
    }
}
```

then, I call it in main class:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Connection conObject = new Connection();
    SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(conObject.SetConnection());
    String sql = "insert into category(cat_id, cat_name) values('C03', 'Browser')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, scon);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

But it isnt work.

How to create a connection class and call it in others class?

Please help me!

thanks.

Comment: As far as I understand you want encapsulating a DB connection into the class and inject in other classes to reuse it, please describe what you are going to do

Comment: What kind of connection are you talking of? What do you want to achieve, what have you tried? Why do you need a class to encapsulate your connection(asssuming rdbms)?

Comment: Why no conn.Open() call?

Comment: I will just let you know that a "connection class" is a bad idea.  When you connect to your SQLConnection it already is pooled, this means the .NET Framework already does all the work for you.  Your just going to break what already works by creating a "connection" class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah like zenwalker said, there is no scon.Open() which you need to open the connection to the database. Also it's better practice to use a using-block when you open the connection like this

```
using(SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(conObject.SetConnection())) {
    scon.Open();
    String sql = "insert into category(cat_id, cat_name) values('C03', 'Browser')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, scon);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Also see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more information about the SqlConnection.

Comment: This is the correct way to achieve what the author wants without a stupid custom class that duplicate what is already done.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Create Class Like

```
 public class ConClass
{
   public SqlConnection Connection()
   {
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=AHM-0149043-D;Integrated Security=True");
       return con;
   }
}
```

then call it from whenever you want like

```
  ConClass c = new ConClass();
  SqlConnection s= c.Connection();
```

Comment: I have to give this a -1 vote for the fact you don't mention this type of class is a BAD idea.